# WPF MVVM: How to get data from delegate in receiving viewmodel?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I have an app that needs certain data to be "global" as it needs to be accessible from any page. Because the app is view-first, I decided to use a messenger to pass this global data from viewmodel to viewmodel since I can't pass it in the constructors. I've managed to pass the data to a second viewmodel, but the problem is that I can't figure out how to actually access and use it.

Here's the code first:

#### Page1 ViewModel

```
public class Page1ViewModel : ObservableObject
{
    // Delegate declaration
    public delegate void SendDeviceEventHandler(object source, DeviceEventArgs e);
    public event SendDeviceEventHandler SendDeviceEvent;

    // Command to Send Data
    public RelayCommand SendDataToPage2 { get; set; }

    // Ctor
    public Page1ViewModel()
    {
        Device = new DeviceModel("SP-2", "Super Processor");
        SendDataToPage2 = new RelayCommand(SendDataToPg2);
    }

    // Command Method sends data to pg2VM
    private void SendDataToPg2(object obj)
    {
        this.SendDeviceEvent += Page2ViewModel.GetDevice;
        OnSendDevice(Device);
    }

    protected virtual void OnSendDevice(DeviceModel device)
    {
        if (SendDeviceEvent != null)
            SendDeviceEvent(this, new DeviceEventArgs() { DeviceToSend = device });
    }

    private DeviceModel _device;
    public DeviceModel Device
    {
        get { return _device; }
        set 
        {
            _device = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged();
        }
    }
}

// Lets us send type "Device" as arg
public class DeviceEventArgs : EventArgs
{
    public DeviceModel DeviceToSend { get; set; }
}
```

#### Page2 ViewModel

```
public class Page2ViewModel : ObservableObject
{
    private DeviceModel device {get; set;}
    // Ctor
    public Page2ViewModel()
    {
       Device = device;  // <- doesn't work 
    }

    // Receive our data here
    public static void GetDevice(object source, DeviceEventArgs e)
    {
        device = new DeviceModel("","");
        device = e.DeviceToSend;
        Trace.WriteLine(device.Name);  // <- Correct Data is here
    }

    private static DeviceModel _device;
    public static DeviceModel Device
    {
        get { return _device; }
        set
        {
            _device = value;
            RaiseStaticPropertyChanged(EventArgs.Empty);
        }
    }
}
```

I'd like to be able to use the sent data as if it was created in Pg2VM, just like how we could use the public `Device` to bind to and modify. The code above shows my last attempt, but I've tried many more including using the property `Device` directly in `GetDevice`. That will correctly set the data with a Trace.WriteLine but I can't bind to `Device`, it's always null.

How can we make that work?

There's something else I'm concerned about which may be the actual issue. To switch views, I use a `Click` event in a button to call the `NavigationService`, and the view will then instantiate the viewmodel via setting the DataContext. In that same button I use the `Command` to activate the messenger to send the data.

If we subscribe to the message the normal way, we have to use something like this:

```
Page2ViewModel pg2 = new Page2ViewModel();
this.SendDeviceEvent += pg2.GetDevice;
```

This would then result in 2 instances of Pg2VM and wouldn't work. Instead, I made the subscriber `static` to avoid this but it feels like bad practice:

```
// In Page1VM
// Command Method sends data to pg2VM
private void SendDataToPg2(object obj)
{
    this.SendDeviceEvent += Page2ViewModel.GetDevice;
    OnSendDevice(Device);
}

// In Page2VM
// Receive our data here
public static void GetDevice(object source, DeviceEventArgs e)
{
    device = new DeviceModel("","");
    device = e.DeviceToSend;
}
```

Is this bad to do? Is there a better approach to sending data in a view-first app than what I'm doing?

Comment: Create a global `ViewModel` that is passed from page to page via the pages constructor. If you have shared data, you don't need a `ViewModel` for each page. Also, why can you not pass via VM constructors? You should definitely be able to do that.

Comment: @Tronald: Because I want to use the `NavigationService` to navigate pages; it's easy and works how I want it to with the journal. But this forces a view-first approach, so the `View` constructs the `ViewModel` and thus we don't have access to the constructor. This should work perfect if we can figure out getting that data passed. I tried making a static class for this but it got nasty fast with trying to manage global and local properties at the same time.